# Google Cloud Location - How can we make the request in one specific country

Tags: google-cloud-platform, geolocation, location, backend

I am a backend developer currently working with Google Cloud for our infrastructure, and we are integrating with a financial partner in France.

Our challenge lies in the geographical requirement specified by this partner. They have informed us that API requests must originate from within France, whereas our Google Cloud setup is currently located outside of France, likely in different regions. Given that all our customers making these API requests are based in France, we need guidance on how to ensure that the requests to that partner are made from within France.

We are seeking insights and best practices on how to configure our Google Cloud infrastructure to meet this specific geographic requirement. Any suggestions or recommendations on configuring the network, utilizing regional services, or any other relevant approaches would be highly appreciated.

We are looking for guidance to set it up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only traffic coming from France, you can use a Load Balancer with [Cloud Armor on it and set a geolocation rule](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#expandable-1)

---

That being said, it's generally a not efficient to filter the traffic source.

- First of all, you can use a proxy. So, the constraint is easy to overpass
- Secondly, related to the first one, Google say: don't trust the network
- Finally, if you have a French customer travelling outside France (even professionally), they are cut from your service.

Prefer identity checks that geolocation.

---

**EDIT 1**

I didn't catch that it was an API call from your Cloud (located outside France) that have to reach an API that check the network location (your partner).

In that case, you could try something (I never tested):

- Create a HTTPS Load Balancer in the Europe-west9 region (France).
- On this Load Balancer, configure [Internet NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts#internet-neg) that point to your Partner APIs
- From your Backend, call the HTTPS Load Balancer located in France

Because the HTTPS Load Balancer is a proxy, it means the traffic is terminated on the Load Balancer, and the Load Balancer create a new connection, from France to your partners.

I never tested. I don't know is the IP that you will get on the France HTTPS Load balancer will be referenced as coming from France. Or reference coming from the USA because it's Google the owner of this IP.

Comment: Merci Guillaume pour votre reponse. C'est sympa.

But it's not about inbound. It's about sending back that API request to the financial partner. Our cloud is located in multiple regions so that request could come from anywhere but they only accept request from that country. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok we will test and let you know :)